# React Router 6 query params

Tags: reactjs

How to get a query parameter in the class component? Match does not work in version 6. I work in typescript.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}></Route>
              <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage/>}/>
              <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductsPage/>}/>
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hooks are the preferred API nowadays and are the main API surface in v6. The easiest way to get access to them is the same as any other hook, just wrap your class component with a functional component that passes along hook values as props. Then use the useSearchParams() hook.

Comment: what about useParams hook?

Comment: Thank you, I understand. But I failed to wrap the class component. What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tried

```
function ProductsPage(){
    let params=useParams();
    return (
        class extends React.Component{
            render() {
                return (
                    <p>{params.id}</p>
                );
            }
        }
    )
}
export default ProductsPage;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a withRouter() for class component that
see below link

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter